# CSS overflow hidden with position absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, css-position

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper .first-column {
  background-color: #c2e0ff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper .first-column .box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  right: -150px;
}
.wrapper .second-column {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  width: 70%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='first-column'>
    <div class='box'>
      content box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='second-column'>
    second-column
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this topic once appeared a few years ago, but let me refresh this topic. I need to find a solution that will allow me to show div.box despite overflow: hidden. Unfortunately, because of the fact that I use the scroll script I can only change the box class.

https://jsfiddle.net/raptorr/Lf3b9yhz/

Comment: do not understand .. `<div class='box'>` is visible? `oveflow: hidden` on what?

Comment: Can you re-prahse your question? Your fiddle and pasted code does not sync. Also as Yalma pointed out, the red box is visible.

Comment: But less than half of the red box is visible.

Comment: @MrLister well haha then he had to say that. i just saw it and went on with my life you know..

Comment: @Ylama Well, the problem looked clear enough to me. The solution is also obvious (remove the `overflow:hidden` from the parent), so, case closed.

Comment: Sorry, link to jsfiddle was wrong. The red box has to go over yellow. Unfortunately, I can't change the overflow on the parent, because I use the scroll script.

https://jsfiddle.net/raptorr/Lf3b9yhz/